# Duplicating an entry on a relationship in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the model `Order` with 2 association to `Address`.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :billing, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'billing_address_id', autosave: true
    belongs_to :shipping, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'shipping_address_id', autosave: true
```

Usually, if both addresses are the same, you would have both associations pointing to the same record, but let's say for a moment, that I wanted to make 2 entries on the table `Address`. How would I do that?

I tried it this way, but it does not seem to work...

```
@order.build_shipping shipping_params
@order.shipping.do_this()
@order.shipping.do_that()

@order.billing = @order.shipping.dup
@order.save
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that both associations point to the same class, wouldn't this work for your case?

```ruby
@order.build_billing(shipping_params)
```

Comment: I would need to repeat "do_this" and "do_that" for billing. I would love to remove that redundance.

Comment: Are this methods altering `billing/shipping` attributes? Also do you need their IDs while doing this?

Comment: Yes, they alter them. No I do not need them